# How would I split this string separate by commas if the first item has two words in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I had a string that was `first second, third`, how would I separate the first two words from the third if there is a comma separating them?

Comment: First two words separate by one white space, then by comma

Comment: @slon How would I handle it if there is an unknown about of words that will be before the comma?

Comment: Show what u have done so far or you'll get more and more downvotes. Row sailor! Row!!!

Comment: `string.split(',')` will split the string using the comma and creates an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.split()` function.

```
var str = "first second, third"
var result = str.split(", ")
```

`result` will be the array `["first second", "third"]`.

Take a look: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @Daedalus I ended up using join(' ') and it appeared to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() function in java with regular expression

Eg :- splinted[] = str.split("[, ]");
You can pass as many as characters you want to split in regex

Or simple alternative is you can first replace space with comma and then split it with comma.

Simple explanation : 
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-split-method-example/